# Convolutional neural networks preserve local connectivity?

Tags: graph-theory, neural-networks, graph-connectivity

I'm working on a project about graph neural networks and was reading some stuff about convolutional neural networks. I did not understand what the book means with 'preserve local connectivity', because in the next sentence they say that it contains fully connected layers as well.

> Convolutional neural networks (CNNs) are special versions of feedworward neural networks (FNNs).
> FNNs are usually fully connected networks while CNNs preserve the
> local connectivity. The CNN architecture usually contains convolutional layers, pooling layers,
> and several fully connected layers

I was hoping someone could explain this to me :)

Edit : I found a nice answer here : [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159588/how-does-local-connection-implied-in-the-cnn-algorithm#:~:text=Each%20input%20(pixel%20value)%20is,EVERY%20part%20of%20the%20image.&text=This%20is%20what%20is%20meant,actually%20close%20to%20each%20other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159588/how-does-local-connection-implied-in-the-cnn-algorithm#:%7E:text=Each%20input%20(pixel%20value)%20is,EVERY%20part%20of%20the%20image.&text=This%20is%20what%20is%20meant,actually%20close%20to%20each%20other).

Comment: Do you know how a convolution filter / kernel works in image processing? It's basically the same.

Comment: I do not, but I will look in to it! Thanks